# UIWebView is crashing when trying to load a local html file

Tags: ios, uiwebview

The code I am using in my view controller viewDidLoad method:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"html"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest* request = [[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url] autorelease];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

I get EXE_BAD_ACCESS

Answer (score 2):

`requestWithURL:` will give you an autoreleased object so you don't need to autorelease it again.